# Scientifically credible texts on how to perform Hypnosis

Tags: reference-request, hypnosis

What are some scientifically credible texts (preferably free and online) that I could read to learn more about Hypnosis.

While hypnosis is a real phenomenon, there seems to be a lot pseudoscience practitioners in the area as well.

Note: I'm looking more for a text book type work explaining how hypnosis works then studies providing evidence for it. It should of course be *supported* by studies, but its main purpose should be instruction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does hypnotherapy/hypnosis, in any form, for any type of disorder, work?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/does-hypnotherapy-hypnosis-in-any-form-for-any-type-of-disorder-work)

Comment: @RobinKramer I edited the question a bit.

Comment: Google Scholar is a great tool for finding credible sources.

Comment: I modified the title to better capture what I think is the difference between this and previous questions. Feel free to revert if I misunderstood.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for two separate things: 1) studies that support hypnotism (to me, this seems answered with [this response](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/4500/7943) to the above question), and 2) for a textbook on hypnotism?

Answer (score 4):

For scientifically supported texts, I would recommend the textbooks produced by the American Society of Clinical Hypnosis (linked [here](http://www.asch.net/Professionals/ASCHBooks.aspx)) as a good place to start. None of these are free (legally), though.

They also produce a bibliography of [articles and books](http://www.asch.net/Public/ASCHBibliography.aspx) (currently some 9 pages) that provide some additional handy references.